# MVC Posting a JS hashtable with multiple types of values into an MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a js object build like this:

```
    var entity = new Object();
    entity["1"] = Property1.GetValue();
    entity["2"] = Property2.GetValue();
    entity["3"] = Property3.GetValue();
    entity["4"] = Property4.GetValue();
    entity["5"] = Property5.GetValue();
    entity["6"] = Property6.GetValue();
    entity["7"] = Property7.GetValue();
    entity["8"] = Property8.GetValue();
    entity["9"] = Property9.GetValue();
    entity["10"] = Property10.GetValue();
    entity["11"] = Property11.GetValue();
    entity["12"] = Property12.GetValue();
    entity["13"] = Property13.GetValue();
    entity["14"] = Property14.GetValue();
    entity["15"] = Property15.GetValue();
```

And i am posting it like this:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify(
    {
        entityID: 1,
        data: entity
    });
    $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Entity/Update",
            data: data, 
            contentType: "application/json", 
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) { 
                alert("koko");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert(xhr.status); 
                alert(ajaxOptions); 
                alert(thrownError); 
            }
    });
```

The post is but the MVC controller gets a null parameter for the data parameter.

MVC method :

```
    public void Update(int entityID, IDictionary<string, object> data)
```

The problem is that the values can be of different types, not only strings or integers. Thats the problem.
Is there a way to cause the default model binder to read the object properly or do i have to write a custom model binder?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go deep into why it doesn't work in MVC3 (something wrong with deserialization?), but I checked it in MVC4 - everything works perfectly.

If your are not able to switch to MVC4, my suggestion would be to refactor your `data` object. I don't know how close your example to your real problem, but you can use array instead of dictionary - in any case your dictionary keys are indices...

So the following will work in MVC3:

```
var entity = [
    Property1.GetValue(),
    Property2.GetValue(),
    Property3.GetValue(),
    Property4.GetValue()
];
```

and

```
public void Update(int entityID, List<object> data)
```

As for using non-primitive types as result of `PropertyN.GetValue()` check out that article: http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/01/10/asp-net-mvc-3-improved-jsonvalueproviderfactory-using-json-net/

The technique in the article allows you to deserialize custom JSON objects as `dynamic` C# type. So you will have the following signature of your action method:

```
public void Update(int entityID, IDictionary<string, dynamic> data)
```